# add custom style to react-sortable-tree

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I'm using `react-sortable-tree` library with typescript and `react-sortable-tree-theme-minimal` and I got this result
[image]

I need to make a small space between the arrow and the title like this
[image]

See the defense between `Tokyo and  Jászárokszállás`
I add `.less` file with styling code

```
.rstcustom__rowTitle {
    margin-left: 1% !important;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

and import it into my component `import '../view/LayoutDepartmentSettings/Style.less';`

and use it with the tree

```
                <SortableTree
                    rowHeight={50}
                    treeData={this.state.treeData}
                    onChange={this.updateTreeData}
                    canDrag={false}
                    className={"rstcustom__rowTitle"}
.......
```

but the style doesn't change and the tree didn't affected.
please tell me where is my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me, I solved the issue by adding `css loader` to `webpack.config` file

Answer (score 0):

Add style inside your component that will help you.

````
<SortableTree
 rowHeight={50}
 treeData={this.state.treeData}
 onChange={this.updateTreeData}
 canDrag={false}
 className={"tree"}
 style={{marginLeft:3,fontWeight:"lighter",color:"red"}}
                     
/>```
````

Comment: I do try it but The space doesn't applied too bad issue

Comment: the marginLeft affects the entire tree ... I want it to affect the text only

Comment: give marginleft inside your list element tag   <li>

Comment: thanks for helping me, I solved the issue by adding css loader to webpack.config file

Comment: Can you please share your codesand box? Thanks..!!